# Detecting ENTER key in C++

Tags: c++

I have a program like this,

```
char name[100];
char age[12];
cout << "Enter Name: ";
cin >> name;

cout << "Enter Age: ";
cin >> age;
```

Now age is a optional field, so user can simply press ENTER key and have that value as NULL. But the problem is, cin doesn't take ENTER key and just stay there waiting for a valid keyboard char or numerical input.

I think the problem is because cin needs a valid input and thus stays there forever.

So i tried below approach to detect ENTER key press for Age.

```
cout << "Enter Age: ";
if (cin.get() == '\n') {
            cout << "ENTER WAS PRESSED" << endl;
        }
```

Now as soon as user presses ENTER key after entering a NAME, it goes straight to the IF condition.

I also tried:

```
getline(cin, age);
```

But that also simply doesn't stop at `cout << "Age: ";` waiting for an input from the user.

The user can either a valid age or simply press ENTER key not to enter a age.

For the below Code:

```
cout << "Enter Name: ";
        cin >> name;

        cout << "Enter Age: ";
        if (cin.get() == '\n') {
            cout << "ENTER WAS PRESSED" << endl;
        }
```

The Output is:

```
Enter Name: asdf
Enter Age: ENTER WAS PRESSED
```

I want the cursor to wait at **Enter Age: _**

How can i do that?

Comment: If you want the cursor to wait at `Enter Age: _`, then where do you want to see the output?

Comment: Do you want the cursor to wait at enter age even when user presses enter?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you tried this?:

```
cout << "Press Enter to Continue";
cin.ignore();
```

also check out [this question](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/2624/)

Comment: I cant use `cin >> myString`, but I can use `std::getline(std::cin, myString)` after `cin.ignore()`

Comment: cin.ignore() doesn't work. It gives signal: terminated, I suspect be it thinks it's read an EOL.

Answer (score 7):

One way to do it is to use getline to read the input, then test the length of the input string. If they only press enter, the length of the line will be 0 since getline ignores newlines by default.

```
std::string myString = "";

do {
     std::cout << "Press ENTER to exit" << std::endl;
     std::getline(std::cin, myString);
} while (myString.length() != 0);

std::cout << "Loop exited." << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are several problems with your code:

1. you are calling `operator>>` with `char[]` buffers without protection from buffer overflows.  Use `std::setw()` to specify the buffer sizes during reading.  Otherwise, use `std::string` instead of `char[]`.
2. `cin >> name` reads only the first whitespace-delimited word, leaving any remaining data in the input buffer, **including the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key**, which is then picked up by `cin >> age` without waiting for new input.  To avoid that, you need to call `cin.ignore()` to discard any unread data.  Otherwise, consider using `cin.getline()` instead (or `std::getline()` for `std::string`), which consumes everything up to and including a linebreak, but does not output the linebreak (you should consider using this for the `name` value, at least, so that users can enter names with spaces in them).
3. by default, `operator>>` skips leading whitespace before reading a new value, **and that includes line breaks**.  You can press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> all you want, `operator>>` will happily keep waiting until something else is entered.  To avoid that, you could use `std::noskipws`, but that causes an unwanted side effect when reading character data - leading whitespace is left in the input buffer, which causes `operator>>` to stop reading when it reads a whitespace character before any user input is read.  So, to avoid that, you can use `cin.peek()` to check for an entered linebreak before calling `cin >> age`.

Try something more like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <iomanip>

char name[100] = {0};
char age[12] = {0};

std::cout << "Enter Name: ";
std::cin >> std::setw(100) >> name;
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
/* or:
if (!std::cin.getline(name, 100))
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
*/

std::cout << "Enter Age: ";
if (std::cin.peek() != '\n')
    std::cin >> std::setw(12) >> age;
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Or:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

std::string name;
std::string age;

std::cout << "Enter Name: ";
std::cin >> name;
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
/* or:
std::getline(std::cin, name);
*/

std::cout << "Enter Age: ";
if (std::cin.peek() != '\n')
    std::cin >> age;
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
/* or:
std::getline(std::cin, age);
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use `cin.get()` compiler will take the lastly used Enter(i.e Enter key pressed while entering name). so you need to make the compiler to avoid the lastly entered Enter key to do so you need to include `cin.ignore()` before using `cin.get()`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to cin into a char variable and then check if it the ENTER key, and if not, continue getting characters and turn them into an int (using character substraction and all that). It is not a very pretty solution but it is the first thing that came into my head.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
std::cout << "\nPress Enter to continue"; 
fgetc(stdin);
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

See more at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgetc/

Answer (score 0):

you can include the "conio.h" library
and use getch();

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

cout << "press enter";
getch();

return 0;

}
```